# Can i use single Zephyr test case to maintain record of test execution on multiple device?

Tags: testing, jira, testcase, test-suite, jira-zephyr

Background->So i am using Zephyr for Test case management.I have a manual test suit with around 100 test cases .All test cases i have to execute on around 10 mobile devices.
I dont want to write same test cases for 10 devices as it will become huge(100X10),rather i was exploring if in any case i can use same zephyr test case for all 10 devices and get reports separate for 10 devices.The problem is execution will be done by multiple testers and keeping just 1 test case will also be a problem as all testers can not kep on executing  the same test case . Any solution to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that my group is using the Zephyr for Jira plugin, the solution my group is experimenting with track release sign off across our platform matrix is:

- Create test cases
- Create a cycle to track release sign off
- Create a folder under the cycle to represent one platform/device (think test run)
- Add test cases to folder (think test results for this platform)
- Clone the folder and it's contents, rename to next platform
- Repeat the cloning until entire matrix covered
- Testers go into each folder to run tests and log results

It looks like the reporting is broken out by folder in the Cycle Summary page in Jira. Which means it's possible to track progress by platform/device.